# Android: broadcast receiver to android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE not working on Android 11

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

The application has a broadcast receiver listening to the changes in service state (in my case mainly network state and SIM card state). It works fine on Android 10 and below, but not working on Android 11 where the broadcast receiver is never triggered. I have checked Android 11 release document but didn't find much useful.

This is how broadcast receiver defined:

AndroidManifest

```
  <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".StateChangesReceiver">
     <intent-filter android:priority="100">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE"/>
     </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

StateChangesReceiver.kt

```
class StateChangesReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

  override fun onReceive(ctx: Context, intent: Intent) {
      // receiver logic
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you see any permission errors in the logs for when you expect your receiver to trigger?

Comment: I saw the errors in the logs. Thanks for the advice @AlwaysLearning

Answer (score 2):

After troubleshooting, there are basically two issues:

1. `android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE` requires `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` permission which is in dangerous level and removed from the app some time ago.
2. Implicit broadcast is not allowed due to [Broadcast Limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts)

My solution is to use more specific system broadcast actions (in my case `android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED` and `android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE`) to avoid strict permission and register broadcast receiver in activity instead of Manifest.

Activity.kt

```
private fun registerBroadcastReceiver() {
    updateReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            // receiver logic
        }
    }
    registerReceiver(updateReceiver, IntentFilter().apply {
        addAction("android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED")
        addAction("android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE")
    })
}
```